# What are the differences between "seems not" and "doesn't seem"?

Tags: differences, negation, gerund-vs-infinitive

Are the following sentences correct?

> He seems not to want to help us

and

> He seems want to help us.

Is it correct if I use "*seem*" in a negative sentence? Which role does "*seem*" play?

Is there any difference in meaning between:

- *It **seems not** working for me.*
- *It **doesn't seem** work for me.*
- *It **seems not** to be working.*

Please tell me the differences between the three of them and in *which situation* I can use them.

Comment: Yes, seem **can** have a negative connotation. Do **not** use seem where its implication is not immediately obvious from context.

Comment: **@Josh61**: I don't think my question is the same with that one.

Comment: For a correct usage of the verb to SEEM have a look here: http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/seem

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think they are correct, close and understandable but not how a native English speaker would say it, I would say

- "**He seems to not want us to help**" and
- "**He seems to want us to help**"

negative questions are usually confusing so I'm not sure I can help you there.

- "**It seems to not be working for me**"
- "**It doesn't seem to work for me**" would be the same meaning.
- "**It seems to not be working**" would also be the same though applied to 'it' not just you working 'it'.

I think the difference is perhaps when spoken rather than written sometimes people miss/slur ot half say things as there is a lot more context.

Comment: Your answer is excellent. I would say that the last bullet point: "It seems to not be working" would never actually be used. People would say, instead, "It doesn't seem to be working." Which is rephrased from your second to last bullet point. In other words, good job.

Comment: Thank you very much. I appreciate all your help. As your answer, Could you please let me know which ones are more formal in writing and which ones are used in speaking?

Comment: Well they are all usable in written or spoken settings,but they seem rather clunky and passive particularly in a spoken setting.  e.g. It seems to not be working, most people would be saying it's broken, or other slang :)

Answer (score 0):

Technically speaking, the 'answer' is wrong: inserting a 'not' in between the 'to' and a verb in its infinitive form (i.e. 'to not want', 'to not be') is NEVER proper English;  that's called a 'split infinitive'.  The negation 'not' should go on one side or the other of the infinitive - immediately adjacent to it.  Howvever, *informally* split infinitives are very common in usage...

Comment: Infinitives absolutely can be split in English. They can't in Latin, which is why some people think they shouldn't be split in English, but this is not the case.